# May I Offer Money to People Who Answer My Question on MathOverflow?

Tags: discussion

Erdos and others have offered prize money to people who answered their questions.
May I offer money to people who answer my questions on MathOverFlow?

Comment: Imaginary internet points aren't enough?

Comment: tea archive [is currently down](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4438), but one can find in the Wayback Machine this discussion: [Is this question acceptable?: 100€ bounty: Do invariant measures maximize the integral?](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910105257/https://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1212/100-bounty-do-invariant-measures-maximize-the-integral/)
It was related to this questions: [Do invariant measures maximize the integral?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/74387) And it links to this one as another example: ...

Comment: ... [How many integer partitions of a googol (10^100) into at most 60 parts](https://mathoverflow.net/q/71092).
There was also this question: [Positive integers written as $\binom{w}2+\binom{x}4+\binom{y}6+\binom{z}8$ with $w,x,y,z\in\{2,3,\ldots\}$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/323541)

Comment: Perhaps this post is tangentially related: [Should metaMO allow actual requests for mathematical consulting services to be remunerated either by honoraria or by "usual and customary" fees?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3521)
And there is this discussion on [meta.se]: [Offering actual money as a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25615) Several of [the linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/25615) is related to the same topic.

Comment: Do you mean to offer the money before the question is answered, as an inducement, or after it's been answered, as a gesture of thanks?

Comment: I'd be against posts proposing money in exchange of an answer, because I appreciate the fact that questions on MO are ranked and considered according to their interest and popularity, and not according to the owner's ability/will to provide money.

Comment: @David Roberts I meant offering money before the question is answered.

Comment: Well, what if you post a particular question and then include in the post the link to your website listing bounties for them? Then it is up to the person whether they want to collect it to contact you about it. But then you will have to do the work to verify if that person is them or not. So it sounds pretty hard from your end.